# Some of the normals have been flipped when in tried converting my model to low poly

Tags: normals

I have used decimate option for converting my model to low-poly after doing that some of the normals have been flipped. I haven't understood that why is it happen. can anyone suggest me solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you show screenshots of the model. Generally Decimate modifier if you used it doesn't flip normals, probably what happened is that shading for the left faces corrupted for some spots. But it's a guess with known information

Comment: the only case it might do that is if you have some kind'a concave shape with less polygons. Try adding a subdivision modifier before the decimate so you could increase the ratio trying to get similar results without the normal problem, but it is just a guess.It'd would help if you could provide a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

You can easily flip all your faces into one direction by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> 
This should solve your problem.